# is it possible to get data of objects of a list using mysql script?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, join

have a json query that gives me json of a joined table of person and pets:

```
SELECT 
    json_object(
        'personId', p.id,
        'firstPetName', p.firstPetName,
        'pets', json_arrayagg(
                   json_object(
                   'petId', pt.id,
                   'petName', pt.name
                  )
                 )
                )
     FROM person p
     LEFT JOIN pets pt ON p.id = pt.person_id
     GROUP BY p.id;
```

I want to add a condition that if `p.firstPetName` is null or empty string to put the `pt.petName` of the first pet in the pets list, is that possible?

example:

if this is the result:

```
{
  "personId": 1,
  "firstPetName": null // or ""
  "pets": [
    {
      "petName": "walker"
    },
    {
      "petName": "roxi"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd would like to get:

```
{
  "personId": 1,
  "firstPetName": "walker"
  "pets": [
    {
      "petName": "walker"
    },
    {
      "petName": "roxi"
    }
  ]
}
```

if it was possible to do something like `pt[0].petName` it was awesome

Comment: As there is no `ORDER BY` clause in the query, how do we know for sure what is the first pet name ?

Comment: @DanielE. no cant count on that...

Comment: @GMB just the first pet object in the list.

Comment: @DanielE. just the first pet object in the list. like if it was possible to do something like ```pt[0].petName``` that would be good

Comment: @jackmiao then how is it the first item in the list ? With your example I really think it's the id.

Comment: @GMB why did you take of the answer with COALESCE? seams like this is what i need...isn't it?

Comment: @jackmiao : I undeleted my answer, however to get a proper answer you would still need to give us the sort criteria...

Comment: there is no sort criteria, I just need the first object that is in the list, the head..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) :

> `JSON_ARRAYAGG(col_or_expr) [over_clause]`
>
> Aggregates a result set as a single JSON array whose elements consist of the rows. *The order of elements in this array is undefined*.

Hence, in your use case, the order of pets in the list is not defined. You cannot know for sure which pet will appear first in the json array generated by the `json_arrayagg` call.

The following query gives an answer that defaults to pet with the minimum name. The `COALESCE` function is then used to provide a default value for `p.firstPetName`.

```
SELECT 
    json_object(
        'personId', p.id,
        'firstPetName', COALESCE(p.firstPetName, MIN(pt.name))
        'pets', json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
                'petId', pt.id,
                'petName', pt.name
            )
        )
    )
FROM 
    person p
    LEFT JOIN pets pt ON p.id = pt.person_id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: Walker > Roxi, we can't answer until we know the order :/

Comment: @DanielE / Walker.: but will we ever get it ?... Anyway I guess you are right, let me put my answer on hold for the time being...

Comment: @DanielE. there is no sort criteria, I just need the first object that is in the list, the head..

Comment: @DanielE. : well I guess we raeally can't know the order, see my updated answer

Comment: @GMB you right, thanks for the detailed answer. luckily in my specific case that works too. thanks